# Retornar um " SELECT * FROM" no navegador JavaWeb

Tags: java, mysql, aplicação-web, jsp, padrão-dao

Olá pessoal estou estudando JavaWeb e me deparei com um erro chato!!
Já pesquisei muito sobre o assunto porém não consegui resolver este erro.

Tenho este método que está puxando todos os dados da tabela "contatos" do banco de dados e retornando em uma lista.

```
public   ArrayList<User> buscarTodos() {
    //Monta a Query
    String sql = "select * from contatos";
    //Constroi PreparedStatement com SQL
    ArrayList<User> lista = new ArrayList<User>();
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparador = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet resultado = preparador.executeQuery();
        while (resultado.next()){
            User contato = new User();
            contato.setContato_id(resultado.getInt("contato_id"));
            contato.setContato_nome(resultado.getString("contato_nome"));
            contato.setContato_tel(resultado.getString("contato_tel"));
            contato.setContato_email(resultado.getString("contato_email"));
            contato.setContato_sobrenome(resultado.getString("contato_sobrenome"));

            lista.add (contato);
        }
        preparador.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return lista;

}
```

Porém quando eu vou exibir essa lista ela retorna apenas o último contato repetido em várias vezes, como na imagem abaixo: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código chamando o método:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Chamando Método Get");
    String acao = request.getParameter("acao");
    UsuarioDAO contatoDAO = new UsuarioDAO();


    if (acao!= null && acao.equals("exc")  ) {
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        User contato = new User();
        contato.setContato_id(Integer.parseInt(id));
        contatoDAO.excluir(contato);
    } 



    List<User> lista = contatoDAO.buscarTodos();

    //Atribuir a Lista no request
    request.setAttribute("lista", lista );

    //Encaminhando para o JSP
    RequestDispatcher saida= request.getRequestDispatcher("exibeContatos.jsp");
    saida.forward(request, response);
}
```

Conseguem me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Comment: Posta seu HTML, por favor

Answer (score 1):

testei aqui e rodou!, passa a sua JSP para vermos como esta esse foreach.

```
public List<User> buscarTodos() throws Exception {

    List<User> results = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM contatos;";

    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery()) {

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            results.add(populate(resultSet));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return results;
}
```

// popula com esse metodo

```
private User populate(ResultSet resultado) throws SQLException {

    User contato = new User();
    contato.setContato_id(resultado.getInt("contato_id"));
    contato.setContato_nome(resultado.getString("contato_nome"));
    contato.setContato_tel(resultado.getString("contato_tel"));
    contato.setContato_email(resultado.getString("contato_email"));
    contato.setContato_sobrenome(resultado.getString("contato_sobrenome"));

    return contato;
}
```

Comment: Coloquei o jsp aqui em baixo

Answer (score 0):

Algumas dicas que podem lhe ajudar:

**1)** Verifique sua tabela na base de dados.

**2)** Verifique a Lista retornada exatamente pelo DAO, sem passar pela tela.

**3)** Coloque o método de listar os contatos, no construtor da classe. Pois o do GET pode está sendo chamado para cada linha da tabela.

**4)** Tente passar seu SQL, como parametro do *executeQuery*

```
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql.toString());
```

Comment: Coloquei o jsp aqui em baixo

Answer (score 0):

Segue o JSP:

(Estava dando erro quando eu coloquei ele completo então segue a imagem com os marcadores "<% %>".)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
List<User> lista = (List<User>) request.getAttribute("lista");

for (User contato : lista){



<tr>
<td><%= contato.getContato_id() %> </td> 
<td><%= contato.getContato_nome() %></td>
<td><%= contato.getContato_sobrenome()%></td> 
<td><%= contato.getContato_tel() %></td> 
<td><%= contato.getContato_email() %></td>
<td><a href = "contatocontroller.do?acao=exc&id=<%= contato.getContato_id() %>">Excluir

    <a href = "contatocontroller.do?acao=alt&id=<%= contato.getContato_id() %>">Alterar
</td>
</tr>


<%

} 

%>
```